# Addition of Inline Quotes

Tags: feature-request, markdown

You can have

```
code blocks
```

that can be instead shown as `inline code`. Similarly, you can have

> block quotes

However, you cannot have "inline quotes". Often, I find I want to add a quote inline, so as to not disrupt the flow of text. Is it possible for this to be added as a feature, or are there reasons as to why it hasn't been already (such as others not sharing the same view as myself)?

Comment: Aren't "inline quotes" inline quotes already? Or do you want the background colour to change?

Comment: Could the inline quote also be enabled on comments? I often find myself including part of the post I'm commenting on/ linking to some documentation and cannot *quote* it (and end up `coding` it or *italicising* it).

Comment: @ChrisF Yes, I mean with the highlighting.

Comment: @Matt I do the same.

Comment: Inline code needs to be very distinct and might have syntax highlighting which makes the separation necessary, I don't think inline quotes need any sort of highlighting.

Comment: What would an online quote look like? Would it be different from using quotation marks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always use the *Emphasis* feature to inline quote something as it is pretty much what it is supposed to be used for.

You can use both *Strong* and *Emphasis* for very important quotes if you want.

Examples:

```
_Less important_
```

*Less important*

```
___Very important quote.___
```

***Very important quote.***

Comment: The problem is that italics sometimes reduce emphasis, and bold increases it too much. Sometimes, especially in fairly long comments like this one, I want to quote something fairly lengthy like "*I always use the Empasis feature to inline quote something as it is pretty much what it is supposed to be used for.*". That starts to get pretty messy, pretty quickly. Whereas a nice `code quote` separates it nicely. We clearly feel a need for a blockquote, despite the fact quote marks and emphasis do the same job for blocks, so why not inline too?

Comment: One problem is with comments, especially if someone is trying to include a two-or-three sentence quote from documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There's the `<q>` [HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/q), presuming it works.

Let's see! Here's a profound quotation.

Nope! Too bad.

Comment: Part of me thinks I should delete this, but I feel that the fact that it doesn't work here is relevant. I'd do it as a comment, but HTML doesn't work in comments. Feel free to downvote, I guess.

Comment: You should use the [sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/323179) for testing.

Comment: See: "[What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/271271)"