# How to write good formatted answers at Chinese SE?

Tags: discussion, markdown

Since no one at Meta Chinese SE answers my question, I am asking MetaStackOverflow for help.

I am just wondering, is there something official for how to write good formatted answers at ChineseSE? For example, when to use strong, emphasis or block quote.I often edit people's answers like "例子" to `例子`. Is that correct?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Chinese..

Comment: [Addition of Inline Quotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120361/addition-of-inline-quotes) likes your vote. (Though in English, and possibly in Chinese too, "..." can easily be used for inline quotes.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `inline code block` are for inline code blocks.  They are not for emphasis of non-code related text.  Use either *italics* or **bold** text for emphasis of text.

> Block quotes

Are for signifying quoted text.  They are also not for emphasis of non-quoted text.

Comment: Many people at ChineseSE use inline code block for better look.

Comment: @AveMaleficum I stand by my answer.  Many people on SO use code blocks for emphasis to.  I (and others) edit out such improper use of formatting, because that's not what code blocks are for.

Comment: I guess you are right, Sir. Ok, I will only `use inline code block`for inline code block.

Comment: @AveMaleficum Note that in some cases, you may need to use the html tags to bold or italicize characters as the simpler markdown syntax [doesn't always work](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/120/issues-with-bolding).